# Не работает скрипт Garry's mod lua

Tags: lua

При открытии меню должен запускаться скрипт, но он не запускается.

```
hook.Add('c_menu','OpenMenu', function(ply)
   if SANDBOX:ContextMenuOpened() == true then
     CmdDerma() 
     print('Context menu is open')        
   end
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если еще не разобрался, то я готов помочь.
Во первых хука c_menu нету, юзай https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/GM:OnContextMenuOpen это. И еще у тебя лишний код в if'е. == true - бессмысленно, т.к. if и так срабатывает на true.

Готовый вариант:

```
concommand.Add('cmenu', function()
    CmdDerma() 
    print('Context menu is open')
end)

hook.Add('OnContextMenuOpen', 'Into_C_Menu', function() 
    if !LocalPlayer():KeyDown( IN_ATTACK2 ) then
        RunConsoleCommand('cmenu') 
    else
        return false
    end
end )
```